# how can i improve my SQL query in MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, subquery

how can improve my query so that only those records should be selected those are not selected yet in Pasenger_Detail table.

```
Private Sub BR_ID_LostFocus()
   Dim s As String

   s = "Select seat_no.seat_no" & _
       " FROM Seat_No" & _
       " Where seat_no.seat_no <=  " & _
       " (select br_info.Seats_Reserved from br_info where "  & _
       " Br_info.br_id=forms!pasenger_detail!br_id);"

  Me.Seat_No.RowSource = s
  Me.Seat_No.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: can you submit table definitions?

Comment: i added pic of relationship might be it help u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Not In in your WHERE clause like below.  If it does not find the seat in the sub query then it will list seat_no in the results.

```
SELECT Seat_No.seat_no 
FROM Seat_No 
WHERE Seat_No.seat_no <= 
(
  SELECT br_info.Seats_Reserved 
  FROM br_info 
  WHERE br_info.br_id = forms!pasenger_detail!br_id
) 
AND Seat_No.seat_no NOT IN 
(
  SELECT pasenger_detail.seat_no 
  FROM pasenger_detail
)
```

Comment: boss i did it earlier and was working. but problem with this is shows those seat nos which  are not being selected yet. but it show all fields entries from seat _no table, but i need only till those which meet my maximum seat_no criteria.

Comment: in short i need both thing, first which is already working in this query also one you suggested.

Comment: You lost me at hello.  Your English is difficult for me to follow.  Can you explain what is being stored in what table and how they relate to each other?  We obviously need more information.

Comment: i tried to improve it in this way but it does not work.                                                                   "Select seat_no.seat_no" & _
    " FROM Seat_No" & _
    " Where seat_no.seat_no <= (select br_info.Seats_Reserved from br_info where Br_info.br_id=forms!pasenger_detail!br_id) NOT IN (select pasenger_detail.seat_no);"

Comment: That would not work.  It is not a proper SQL statement.  Maybe the following is what you are after: `SELECT Seat_No.seat_no FROM Seat_No WHERE Seat_No.seat_no <= (SELECT br_info.Seats_Reserved FROM br_info WHERE br_info.br_id = forms!pasenger_detail!br_id) AND Seat_No.seat_no NOT IN (SELECT pasenger_detail.seat_no FROM pasenger_detail)`

Comment: boss first of all it work and thanks. the lesson i learn that when ever we put AND to extend our criteria we should once again put comparison table name and field name in it. if it already exists at after where or not. Am i right sir.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I have updated my answer to what worked for you .  If it indeed worked for you please mark as accepted and up-vote.  Glad I could be of help.

Comment: see you again soon with some new problem. thanks for this you save my potential, i was becoming feedup with this thing earlier